# I need to get value from html code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code i need to get backupURL value ..how to get it?

```
var tem="<li><a class="selectBackupFromList" backupURL="http://localhost/3/wordpress/wp-content/infinitewp/backups/localhost-3-wordpress_installClone_full_2015-07-22_9521d628fe5b13281d87d2508e8112c3.zip"><span class="check rep_sprite_backup"></span><span class="bu_name">Backup for Clone</span><span class="bu_time rep_sprite_backup">Jul 22, 2015 @ 07:07pm</span><div class="clear-both"></div></a></li>";
```

how to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your HTML string in jQuery, and then you can use jquery method on it as if it is in DOM. Also, note that your string is breaking. Use single-quote to the string.

```
$(tem).find('.selectBackupFromList').attr('backupURL');
```

**Demo**

```js
var tem = '<li><a class="selectBackupFromList " backupURL="http: //localhost/3/wordpress/wp-content/infinitewp/backups/localhost-3-wordpress_installClone_full_2015-07-22_9521d628fe5b13281d87d2508e8112c3.zip"><span class="check rep_sprite_backup"></span><span class="bu_name">Backup for Clone</span><span class="bu_time rep_sprite_backup">Jul 22, 2015 @ 07:07pm</span><div class="clear-both"></div></a></li>';

alert($(tem).find('.selectBackupFromList').attr('backupURL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```